# Replacing WebFluxSleuthOperators when updating from sleuth to micrometer - Spring boot 3 upgrading

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I am inexperienced with Sleuth, so maybe my question is actually pretty self-evident.

We are updating Spring Boot from 2 to 3 and Sleuth does not work with Spring Boot 3. The problem is that we use this class `WebFluxSleuthOperators` several times and it seems there are no evident candidate for an easy replacement in micrometer library.

Here's my code:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.CurrentTraceContext
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.WebFluxSleuthOperators
import org.springframework.core.Ordered
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

@Component
open class SleuthBaggageToResponseHeadersFilter(
    @Autowired private val tracer: Tracer,
    @Autowired private val currentTraceContext: CurrentTraceContext,
) : WebFilter, Ordered {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        exchange.response.beforeCommit {
            Mono.deferContextual { Mono.just(it) }.doOnNext { addToResponseHeaders(exchange) }.then()
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange)
    }

    private fun addToResponseHeaders(exchange: ServerWebExchange) =
        WebFluxSleuthOperators.withSpanInScope(tracer, currentTraceContext, exchange) {
            val requestId = tracer.getBaggage("REQUEST_ID")?.get() ?: "NOT_FOUND"
            exchange.response.headers.remove("REQUEST_ID")
            exchange.response.headers.add("REQUEST_ID", requestId)
        }

    override fun getOrder() = SleuthBaggageDefaultValuesFilter.ORDER + 1
}
```

What can we use instead for this purpose?

There is a migration guide for this, but I found it to be rather unhelpful for my situation
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide